# "Inline Attachments" images are not shown in mail with Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Regards!

I'm trying to put Attachments Inline images into an Gmail email, but for some reason, images are not shown in the email's body.

I have searched a lot on the Internet and all found answers say same way to do it.

In my Mailer Class:

```
def send_mail
  attachments.inline['imagen.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("public", "borrar.png").to_path)
  mail(to: email, subject: 'test')
end
```

In my mailer view "send_mail.html.erb"

```
<%= image_tag attachments["imagen.png"].url %>
```

The email view

[image]

Ruby Version: ruby 3.2.2
Rails version: Rails 7.0.6
OS: Windows 11 Home.

I need your help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that "File.read" open the file in Text mode.  I had to use File.open for opening the file in Binary mode.

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "borrar.png"), 'rb')
attachments.inline['imagen.png'] = file.read
```